# react-navigation modal with header/back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Implementing a social network, I have the Feed screen, a Post screen and a Compose screen

I need to be able to navigate back and forth on the Feed and Post pages, so they're in the same stack.

The Compose screen needs to be popped up as a model with a separate navbar.

The current implementation is this:

```
const MainStack = new StackNavigator({
    Feed: { screen: Feed },
    Post: { screen: Post },
});
```

I tried two alternatives:

Adding the compose screen to the main navigator
=> there's no header, even when overriding navigation options:

```
export const Navigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    MainStack: { screen: MainStack },
    Compose: { screen: Compose, navigationOptions: { headerMode: "screen" } },
  },
  { headerMode: "none", mode: "modal" }
);
```

Placing Compose screen in a separate stack => we get a header with a back button, but pressing it doesn't go back to the main stack

```
const ComposeStack = new StackNavigator({
    Compose: { screen: Compose },    
});

export const Navigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    MainStack: { screen: MainStack },
    ComposeStack: { screen: ComposeStack },
  },
  { headerMode: "none", mode: "modal" }
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your first alternative, try setting headerMode to `'screen'` so the header appears. Let me know if it does!

Comment: thanks for the response
changing Navigator stack header mode to 'screen' creates  2 nav headers - one for the Navigation stack and one for MainStack - and removing MainStack's header means I can't navigate between A and B

Comment: Ok after thinking about it, you should take an approach similar to your 2nd alternative instead. May I ask how you're navigating to the modal screen `C` and away from it? Also, have you seen this official example? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/modal.html

Comment: Thanks
One example is a social network app: 
A is the Feed, B is a post page which you navigate back and forth
C is the New Post page - it pops up as a modal which you close to go back to the A&B stack
The example is fine, only there's no nav header to the modal

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without having to manually set a header on your modal screen if you setup your stack navigation in the following way:

```
export const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  MainStack: { 
    screen: MainStack,
    navigationOptions: { header: null },
  },
  Compose: { 
    screen: Compose,
  },
}, {
  mode: "modal",
});
```

With this setup, `MainStack` will render without a header and your `Compose` modal will have one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply turn the modal screen into a `StackNavigator`:

```js
const modalStack = StackNavigator({
  Modal: { screen: Modal }
})

export const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  App: { screen: App },
  Modal: { screen: modalStack },
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none'
})
```

To return back to the app from the modal:

```js
function handleBackButtonPressed() {
  navigation.goBack(null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. What happens is that now a custom header left button has been specified  so that you are able to navigate back to e.g. `Post` from the modal. You can replace `Go Back` with a back-arrow icon from a library of your choice.

```
const MainStack = new StackNavigator({
    Feed: { screen: Feed },
    Post: { screen: Post }
}, {
    headerMode: "screen",
    modal: "card"
});

const ComposeStack = new StackNavigator({
    Compose: { 
      screen: Compose, 
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({ 
        headerLeft: 
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Post')}}>
            <Text>Go Back</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity> 
      })
    },    
} );

export const Navigation = StackNavigator({
    MainStack: { screen: MainStack },
    ComposeStack: { screen: ComposeStack },
},
{ 
    headerMode: "none", mode: "modal" 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way loses the navigation from A to B and back via the nav header. (now renamed Feed, Post)

Comment: @Ian.mc I have updated my answer. Try and see if it works for your use case

Comment: Thanks again for your time.
This looks better but I'm not sure I should use it:
1. When navigating from Compose to Post, instead of returning to Post, the Compose screen remains in the state stack and a new MainStack is added on top. It's noticable cisually  -  the Post screen slides up from bottom adding a new stack, instead of the Compose screen sliding down from top, revealing the previous stack
2. This means that if the user did some navigating in MainStack, e.g. Feed => Post1 => User1 => Post2 => Compose => Post2, he wont be able to navigate back in the original history

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually placing react-navigation's internal Header component as described [here](https://medium.com/4thought-studios/better-modals-in-react-navigation-56c649e0249).

Definitely not a perfect solution, but it works.

Would still prefer a better way if somebody knows one.

```
import Header from 'react-navigation/src/views/Header/Header';

class ModalScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
     ...
     <Header scene={{index: 0}}
             scenes={[{index: 0, isActive: true}]}
             navigation={{state: {index: 0}}}
             getScreenDetails={() => ({options: {
                title: 'Modal',
                headerRight: (
                  <Button 
                     title="Close" 
                     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
                  />
                )
             }})}
     />
     ...
   );
  }
}
```